# How can I check whether a user enters the same number twice? C++ Help?

Tags: c++

I just need quick help.  Here's a breakdown of some code:

```
char userLetter;
int userNumber;

cout << "Please enter a letter: ";
cin >> userLetter;

while(userLetter == 'A')
{
     cout << "Please enter a number: ";
     cin >> userNumber;

     //do something in the loop here

     cout << "Please enter a letter: ";
     cin >> userLetter;
}
```

Now I basically need to add something that will tell the user his entry is invalid if he enters the same number more than once.  For example, let's say the user enters the letter A and the number 2.  The while loop executes whatever it needs to do and then asks the user for a letter again.  Let's say the user enters 'A' again.  The loop then asks the user for another number, if the number is 2 again, the program should tell the user it's an invalid entry.

Any help?

Comment: You need to store all the numbers and search through it each time for the number inputted by the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `std::set` to remember all entered numbers and see if each subsequent number is already in the set.

```
std::set<int> numbers;
while(userLetter == 'A')
{
     cout << "Please enter a number: ";
     cin >> userNumber;

     if ( numbers.find(userNumber) != numbers.begin() )
     {
          //prompt error here
          continue;
     }
     else
     {
          numbers.insert(userNumber);
     }

     //do something in the loop here

     cout << "Please enter a letter: ";
     cin >> userLetter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the previous number(s) in a `std::vector` and test for equality after reading the subsequent number(s) with the previously read and stored numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `std::set` of `std::pair`-s, or some `std::map` to keep the association between the letter and the number.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a container (std::set, probably) to store numbers. You can insert with method "insert", and test if a number is in the set with method "find".

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/

Answer (score 0):

```
std::map<char, int> m;
std::map<char,int>::iterator it;

it=m.find(userLetter);
if(it!=m.end() && *it==userNumber)
{ 
    std::cout << "it's an invalid entry" << std::endl;
    continue;
}
```

Comment: I believe there is no correspondence between the letter and number. He just wants to filter out the numbers entered twice.